# Method does not override method from its superclass

Tags: java, android, overriding, superclass

Can anyone tell me, why this error is displayed (or even have a better solution)?
I'm new to Java (and Android) development, so I realy don't know my fault
My Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class select_type extends Fragment {


    public select_type() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override //<--- Cause the ERROR
    public View onCreateView(View view, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select_type, container, false);

        Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                noVIP TextFragment = new noVIP();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, TextFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override two methods also:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select_type, container, false);
}




@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

   Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            noVIP TextFragment = new noVIP();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, TextFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }); 

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
public View onCreateView(View view, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

with:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

as [`onCreateView()` is not passed a `View` parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29).

Also, get rid of `super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);`. It is neither necessary nor appropriate to be calling that where you are.

Please note that everything after your `return` statement in that method will not be executed, since you are returning first. Assign the `inflater.inflate(...)` result to a local variable, use it, then return that variable at the end of your method.

Comment: Ok, but now, how can I make `Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn)`?

Comment: @NiklasZeroZero: Assign the `inflater.inflate(...)` result to a local variable. Feel free to call this `View` `view`. Then, call `findViewById()` on `view`.